# Ideas needed: how to tilt a panel side to side

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, pneumatic

requirements:

- a panel of wood 4 ft long by 2 ft wide laying flat
- this panel should be able to tilt side to side (2 way)
- the weight on the panel will be about 250 lbs up to 400 lbs.
- controlled lift of each side should be max 3 inches

Solutions investigated:

- pneumatic cylinders (price unknown)
- air suspension (for cars) (roughly $250)

Any ideas how this can be done without breaking the bank?

Comment: car seat motors, gears and threaded rods...

Comment: This is essentially a poll.  There are multiple ways that this could be accomplished with little to differentiate what would be the best solution.  And it flirts with the principle of a "naive design question" in the sense that you're asking the community to put together the design for you.  Closing as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the restrictions you've provided, one could establish rotating shafts (axles) under the panel in the appropriate locations. Cams added to these shafts with properly ramped profiles would provide a controlled lift at relatively low cost.

Depending on materials, some mitigation of friction would be needed. Bearing assemblies on which the cams make contacts (cam followers) would add some expense in exchange for extended life.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a lever to the panel and lift or lower one side by hand. Hook it into stops at all the positions you want to hold it at.